# How do I use a variable foo in a function to reference some class bar.foo when foo changes?

Tags: python-3.3

I just started an introduction to CS course that is teaching us python.  I've been fooling around trying to make a program that will generate a character sheet for an rpg game.  I was wondering how to use classes to define items and a function later on to buy/equip said items.  This is pretty much the type of thing I've been doing:

```
class SomeClass:
    class Foo:
        def description():
            print("Description of the Foo item")
            return
    class Bar:
        def description():
            print("Description of the Bar item")
            return

def SomeFunction(item):
    SomeClass.item.function()
    return
```

Some Function would take either Foo or Bar to work, but it hasn't been working for me.  Is there any way to do this at all?

Any help is super duper appreciated.

EDIT: I was shown how to use csv files, so I've switched to using them to deal with items, but I was still interested to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse classes and instances. If you want to call a method of an instance then you need to pass the instance to `SomeFunction` and just call the method on it inside the function. If you want do something else you need more complicated code than you provided.